# How to send Stringified data as body in Postman?

Tags: node.js, postman

I have an IOT service in aws and it posts data to a pipeline. The data posted is in the form of string and the body contains just the string as follows:

```
"{\"Time_Stamp\":1662449255,\"IMEI\":\"860987053151997\",\"BPID\":\"0\",\"Warn\":\"1000\"}\r\n"
```

I am parsing the data to JSON and then extracting it on my server but I want to know that if I wanted to test this in postman then how do I make a request? How to send the following data as body so that I could parse it locally for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

- First and foremost select your request type like - POST, GET, etc
- then select Body and under the body select the 4th option raw
- And after the 5th option there is a dropdown with text, javascript,JSON
  so, select JSON and paste your JSON data and call your API

Comment: I am not talking about posting JSON to the document. I am talking about posting stringified data in body.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution was similar like this [documentation](https://community.postman.com/t/need-help-parsing-this-json-array/837/3)

You can type your JSON, into the raw (JSON). And it will be seen like this picture.

[image]

If you still need to learn more, let's take an exercise session with this [collection](https://community.postman.com/t/need-help-parsing-this-json-array/837).

Thank you

Comment: I am not talking about posting JSON to the document. I am talking about posting stringified data in body.